# Symfony 4, get Logger, get Doctrine, get Rabbit out of the controller

Tags: logging, doctrine, rabbitmq, symfony4

In Symfony 3.3 on the controller I could do:

```
$sendEmailManager = new SendEmailManager($this->container);
```

And in the Manager:

```
private $ container;
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $ container) {
$this->container = $container;
}
```

I could use this in all methods:

```
$logger = $ this->container->get('logger');
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$container->get('old_sound_rabbit_mq.producer_email_text_producer')->publish(json_encode($ dataToRabbit));
```

How can I do this in Symfony 4.4?

Comment: You should define your sendEmailManager as a Service on the services.yml file, and then pass container as argument. Then inject that service on the controller..But I would recommend not inject full container, just that dependencies you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your needed dependencies as follows:

```
class SendEmailManager {
    private $em;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, LoggerInterface $logger, [...]) { // As many as you want..
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, you can inject that class.

In your services.yml, you should have the autowiring set to true because in that way, symfony will register all classes as a services.

Hope it helps